# How can I remove Live Tile updates in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, live-tiles

I have a very slow Internet connection and don't want Live Tiles using up my bandwidth for updates.

Is there a way to shut them off?

I've changed the *Show updates for Tiles* in the settings but still they show up.

Comment: FWIW, you can also [set your connection as being metered](http://www.verboon.info/index.php/2012/10/windows-8metered-connections/) (if you haven't already), which limits Live Tile updates to 50Mb/month, but *also* tells your applications to minimize the amount of bandwidth they consume.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can disable live update for each tile by right-clicking it and choosing "Turn live tile off":

[image: live]

Comment: The better solution is to completely uninstall the bandwidth-sucking Metro apps. I don't trust them at all. This is ridiculous - these live tiles sucked up GBs of data on my cell hotspot and cost my $25+ easily before I figured out what was going on.

Answer (score 14):

In the interface, you do not have an option to change a live tile’s update frequency.
There might be some registry hack to do it.

**An easier way would be:**
To turn off individual tiles, right-click the tile on the Metro startpage, and select the **turn live tile off** option on the bottom toolbar.

[image: Screenshot]

(**[Reference](http://www.ghacks.net/2012/06/26/turning-off-metro-startpage-live-tiles/)**)

Answer (score 10):

If you don't want to do this on a per-app basis, you can disable Live Tile notifications, Toast messages, and communications with the Windows Push Notification Service in the following Local Group Policy branch:

`User Configuration\Administrative Templates\Start Menu and Task Bar\Notifications`

[image]

Comment: and here's know to open the GroupPolicyEditor - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731745.aspx Also note that this works only with Professional edition of windows.

Comment: This setting is available but doesn't seem to disable anything on Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

Just right click on the tile and select `Turn live tile off`

[image]

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want to use the Metro interface with live tiles then you can install Classic Shell which is available at http://classicshell.sourceforge.net/ 
This will remove the Metro interface being default and will default you to the regular desktop with a Start menu.

Comment: Probably because this answer amounts to: "To turn off the bathroom faucet, first remove the plumbing from your house..."

Comment: Genuinely do not think it does, because it doesn't remove anything.

Comment: Reading Comprehension 101: When he says "shut ***them*** off", he's referring to the updates, *not* the live tiles themselves.

Comment: Still... nice to have the start menu back...

Comment: But he didn't ask how to get the start menu back. He asked how to turn off live tile updates.