# How to completely disable all the live tiles across all the metro apps at once?

Tags: windows-8, live-tiles

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I remove Live Tile updates in Windows 8?](https://superuser.com/questions/496906/how-can-i-remove-live-tile-updates-in-windows-8)

Is there a method by which I can toggle on and off live updates for all the tiles in windows 8 in case if I want because some times when I am streaming some videos I want my full bandwidth to be used there.

I have read a post earlier telling me to do this on app by app basis but its not possible for me to go to each app every time to do this.

Comment: [here's how to turn off updates for all apps](http://superuser.com/a/497664/68111).

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know it can only be possible if you right click the app and click on "Turn live tile off". This shouldn't be a problem unless you have 100+ apps.

Also doing it once will disable it until you right click the app again and choose to turn on the live tile.

Comment: +1 : I think this is the only way. There is no documentation on multiple selection.

Comment: I know about this but I if want to toggle all of them on and off frequently I cant do this...